# Using a generic method in a C# class

Tags: c#

Here is my current code:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form 
{
    public Random random = new Random();
    public int[] randomInt = new int[20];
    public double[] randomDouble = new double[20];

    public string searchKey;
    public int intOrDouble; // 0 if int, 1 if double

    public static int Search<T>(T[] inputArray, T key) where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            if (inputArray[i].CompareTo(key) == 0)
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void randomIntGeneration_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        randomNumbersTextBox.Clear(); // empty the textbox
        intOrDouble = 0; // this is for knowing which parameter to send to search method

        // generate 20 random integers and display them in the textbox
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
        {
            randomInt[i] = random.Next(0, 100);
            randomNumbersTextBox.Text += randomInt[i].ToString() + "   ";
        }
    }

    private void randomDoubleGenerator_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        randomNumbersTextBox.Clear(); // empty the textbox
        intOrDouble = 1; // this is for knowing which parameter to send to search method

        // generate 20 random doubles and display them in the textbox
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
        {
            randomDouble[i] = random.NextDouble() + random.Next(0, 100);
            randomNumbersTextBox.Text += randomDouble[i].ToString() + "   ";
        }
    }

    private void searchArrayButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        searchKey = searchKeyTextBox.Text;
        if(intOrDouble == 0) // int array passed
        {
            resultsTextBox.Text = Search(randomInt, searchKey).ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            resultsTextBox.Text = Search(randomDouble, searchKey).ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

}

What i am trying to do is use this generic method. The GUI allows the user to generate a random array of either ints or doubles. I then want to use the Search method in the searchArrayButton_Click control to display whether or not the "searchKey" value entered is in the array. The error I am getting is "The type arguments for method 'Form1.Search(T[], T)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly." They appear toward the bottom of the code when I try to call Search twice in the searchArrayButton_Click control.

Comment: Not totally sure why you have a any-type specifier for the SearchClass, nor what the class wide genericArray is for.. you got your generic search but it doesn't use the class wide variable (and also why is the key always a string, not a T? why does it only search 20 elements?) Forms like Form1 descend from Form; to treat it generically do `Form f = new Form1();` etc. Why have a type unspecified variable in the form? All the places you could get data from in a winform are type fixed at compile time

Comment: You need to improve your `SearchClass`. But even the way it is now, to use the `Search` method, all you need to do is to qualify it with the class name. So from within your button click handler, do this: `SearchClass<int>.Search(new int[] { 1, 2 }, "1");`. I am passing an integer array to it but you need to pass the array form your textbox. I will let you figure that out since it is an assignment so you can learn.

Comment: That's a class, not a method. What is your “generic method” supposed to do because there is a lot of nonsensical code in there.

Comment: Updated: realized what I was doing was wrong and cleaned up my code to make it easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to search an array of `int` or `double` values for a `string`. As a result, your call to Search has two arguments with two different types. That doesn't match the function signature.

You need to convert whatever is in that textbox into the value you are searching for, either an int or a double.

```
if(intOrDouble == 0) // int array passed
{
    resultsTextBox.Text = Search(randomInt, int.Parse(searchKey)).ToString();
}
else
{
    resultsTextBox.Text = Search(randomDouble, double.Parse(searchKey)).ToString();
}
```